# Port-forwarded Rails app in Docker seems to cause CSRF exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, docker, csrf, unicorn

I have a Rails app that runs in a Docker container which is assigned an ip `172.17.0.3`. Incoming requests to the host machine `51.x.x.x` are forwarded to the rails app in `172.17.0.3`. More specifically, this was done as such:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 rails_app
```

However, Rails app throws `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` error when a user tries to access some of the pages. My suspicion is that Rails thinks the incoming request is an attack, since the ip of the destination doesn't match the ip of the Rails app - i.e. user requests are directed to the host machine `51.x.x.x`, whereas Rails actual location is at `172.17.0.3`

Is there any way for me to tell Rails that these requests are legit? As an additional info, I  use `devise` for authentication, and `unicorn` as the server.

Some of you might be tempted to suggest changing `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` to `:null_session`, but the application works just fine when not placed behind a proxy. Besides, some of the logic will not work when I changed that part since I think the setting messes with the way a user session is handled.

This is the layout of my network:

```
(user from public network) ----> (proxy) ----> (rails app on a private network)
        (202.x.x.x)            (51.x.x.x)               (172.x.x.x)
```

EDIT:
The app is in `development` settings. Here's the error I got in `log/development.log` files.

```
Started POST "/register" for 202.x.x.x at 2014-11-18 02:27:11 +0000
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aBG3nIAKK1ALMJ1DDYFlMkmqISMBMZc3iLmaeD2byG8=", "user"=>{"email"=>"email@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:176:in `handle_unverified_request'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:202:in `handle_unverified_request'
  devise (3.4.0) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:251:in `handle_unverified_request'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:197:in `verify_authenticity_token'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack-cors (0.2.9) lib/rack/cors.rb:54:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lint.rb:49:in `_call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
  sinatra (1.4.5) lib/sinatra/base.rb:217:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/chunked.rb:43:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:576:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:670:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
  unicorn (4.8.3) bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I just built a production environment on a ubuntu VM using docker containers... flask, mysql, nginx, and uwsgi. I'm also getting CRSF token errors on forms.

Comment: Just figured something similar myself... If you have SERVER_NAME defined in your config, try removing it.

Comment: @Chockomonkey Can you expand on what you mean? Do you mean if you have `SERVER_NAME` defined as an environment variable?

Comment: @ChrisPeters It was the SERVER_NAME variable in my application configuration. I'm not sure if Rails has something similar, but here's my question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134427/flask-wtf-csrf-validation-fails-when-app-moved-to-docker-production-environment

Comment: @Chockomonkey There isn't a `SERVER_NAME` setting native in Rails, but thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

From a cursory reading of the '[protect_from_forgery method](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods/protect_from_forgery)', we find the following:

```
  def protect_from_forgery(options = {})
    self.forgery_protection_strategy = protection_method_class(options[:with] || :null_session)
    self.request_forgery_protection_token ||= :authenticity_token
    prepend_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, options
    append_after_action :verify_same_origin_request
  end
```

Which has a before action callback called '[verify_authenticity_token](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/verify_authenticity_token)'. If we look at its source we find the following:

```
  def verify_authenticity_token
    mark_for_same_origin_verification!

    if !verified_request?
      logger.warn "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" if logger
      handle_unverified_request
    end
  end
```

From there we note that it calls '[verified_request?](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/verified_request%3F)'.

```
  def verified_request?
    !protect_against_forgery? || request.get? || request.head? ||
      form_authenticity_token == params[request_forgery_protection_token] ||
      form_authenticity_token == request.headers['X-CSRF-Token']
  end
```

Given the nature of the raised exception, I would think that one or more of those conditions are not being met. I don't think that it has anything to do with the IP addressing.

Answer (score 1):

If your rails app is speaking over non-SSL to your proxy, there could be an issue where your ActiveRecord::SessionStore is throwing a fit because of that scenario.

<strike>Our fix was to make the session store insecure:</strike>

`OurApplication::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, secure: false`

Edit: Still no fix yet... We're probably going to have to make the SSL terminate at the apps as opposed to the proxy over this.

So for us, the issue had nothing to do with SSL in the end. We had a javascript call being executed on the first page load that was trying to perform a handshake against a backend service (via a POST), but we hadn't properly configured our HAProxy to route calls to that service, so instead the POST was hitting Rails. Even though Rails returned a 404 for the route, it also reset the session because of the missing CSRF token in the request. Fixing HAProxy's routing fixed the issue.

Our scenario likely has almost nothing to do with yours, and in Rails 4, they made the default behavior of `protect_from_forgery` be to raise an exception instead of resetting the session. Oh, and we did also ultimately need to set the session store to insecure:

`OurApplication::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, secure: false`